# Intellij tomcat 8 run configuration doesn't work

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

So I'm trying to run a web application in an intellij tomcat run configuration, but it isn't working. My rest endpoints return 404. When I run the same app from the command line, the endpoints get hit and work. I was hoping someone could help me figure out what's wrong with what Intellij is doing.

It looks like intellij is starting tomcat, and then deploying the artifact, while running it with the war already in place loads the war while starting tomcat. I also don't see this line in the intellij deploy output, which seems suspicious: `07-Oct-2016 15:00:23.351 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\webapps\coolbooks-rest.war has finished in 6,851 ms`

Here's the output when intellij starts it up (shortened where similar to the other):

```
C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\bin\catalina.bat run
[2016-10-07 03:30:08,782] Artifact coolbooks-rest:war: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\Coray\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_open-coolbooks-aggregator"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
[...]
07-Oct-2016 15:30:10.235 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37
07-Oct-2016 15:30:10.236 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
07-Oct-2016 15:30:10.236 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
07-Oct-2016 15:30:10.236 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
07-Oct-2016 15:30:10.236 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
07-Oct-2016 15:30:10.236 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
07-Oct-2016 15:30:10.236 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
07-Oct-2016 15:30:10.236 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Coray\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_open-coolbooks-aggregator\conf\logging.properties
07-Oct-2016 15:30:10.236 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
07-Oct-2016 15:30:10.236 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\endorsed
07-Oct-2016 15:30:10.237 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Coray\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_open-coolbooks-aggregator
[...]
07-Oct-2016 15:30:11.028 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
07-Oct-2016 15:30:11.028 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.37
07-Oct-2016 15:30:11.034 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
07-Oct-2016 15:30:11.040 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
07-Oct-2016 15:30:11.042 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 29 ms
Connected to server
[2016-10-07 03:30:11,245] Artifact coolbooks-rest:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[...]
07-Oct-2016 15:30:20.110 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.logClasses Root resource classes found:
  class com.coolbooks.rest.category.Category
  class com.coolbooks.rest.geo.Location
  class com.coolbooks.rest.store.Store
  class com.coolbooks.rest.cart.Cart
  class com.coolbooks.rest.basentity.BaseEntity
  class com.coolbooks.rest.content.Content
  class com.coolbooks.rest.crawled.Product
  class com.coolbooks.rest.price.Pricing
07-Oct-2016 15:30:20.110 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init No provider classes found.
07-Oct-2016 15:30:20.445 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.register Registering com.coolbooks.listener.JacksonOMP as a provider class
07-Oct-2016 15:30:20.445 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.register Registering com.coolbooks.rest.basentity.BaseEntity as a root resource class
07-Oct-2016 15:30:20.445 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.register Registering com.coolbooks.rest.cart.Cart as a root resource class
07-Oct-2016 15:30:20.445 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.register Registering com.coolbooks.rest.category.Category as a root resource class
07-Oct-2016 15:30:20.445 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.register Registering com.coolbooks.rest.content.Content as a root resource class
07-Oct-2016 15:30:20.445 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.register Registering com.coolbooks.rest.crawled.Product as a root resource class
07-Oct-2016 15:30:20.445 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.register Registering com.coolbooks.rest.geo.Location as a root resource class
07-Oct-2016 15:30:20.445 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.register Registering com.coolbooks.rest.price.Pricing as a root resource class
07-Oct-2016 15:30:20.445 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.register Registering com.coolbooks.rest.store.Store as a root resource class
07-Oct-2016 15:30:20.448 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM'
07-Oct-2016 15:30:20.520 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider Binding com.coolbooks.listener.JacksonOMP to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
07-Oct-2016 15:30:21.036 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\webapps\manager
07-Oct-2016 15:30:21.072 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\webapps\manager has finished in 36 ms
07-Oct-2016 15:30:21.072 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider Binding com.coolbooks.rest.basentity.BaseEntity to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
07-Oct-2016 15:30:21.090 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider Binding com.coolbooks.rest.cart.Cart to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
07-Oct-2016 15:30:21.095 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider Binding com.coolbooks.rest.category.Category to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
07-Oct-2016 15:30:21.101 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider Binding com.coolbooks.rest.content.Content to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
07-Oct-2016 15:30:21.102 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider Binding com.coolbooks.rest.crawled.Product to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
07-Oct-2016 15:30:21.103 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider Binding com.coolbooks.rest.geo.Location to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
07-Oct-2016 15:30:21.104 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider Binding com.coolbooks.rest.price.Pricing to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
07-Oct-2016 15:30:21.106 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider Binding com.coolbooks.rest.store.Store to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
[2016-10-07 03:30:21,146] Artifact coolbooks-rest:war: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2016-10-07 03:30:21,146] Artifact coolbooks-rest:war: Deploy took 9,901 milliseconds
```

And from running the tomcat server manually:

```
C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\bin>catalina.bat run
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
[...]
07-Oct-2016 15:00:15.948 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37
07-Oct-2016 15:00:15.948 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
07-Oct-2016 15:00:15.948 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\conf\logging.properties
07-Oct-2016 15:00:15.948 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
07-Oct-2016 15:00:15.948 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\endorsed
07-Oct-2016 15:00:15.948 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37
07-Oct-2016 15:00:15.948 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37
07-Oct-2016 15:00:15.948 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\temp
[...]
07-Oct-2016 15:00:16.489 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
07-Oct-2016 15:00:16.489 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.37
07-Oct-2016 15:00:16.500 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\webapps\coolbooks-rest.war
[...]
07-Oct-2016 15:00:22.340 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.logClasses Root resource classes found:
  class com.coolbooks.rest.content.Content
  class com.coolbooks.rest.basentity.BaseEntity
  class com.coolbooks.rest.geo.Location
  class com.coolbooks.rest.price.Pricing
  class com.coolbooks.rest.category.Category
  class com.coolbooks.rest.crawled.Product
  class com.coolbooks.rest.store.Store
  class com.coolbooks.rest.cart.Cart
07-Oct-2016 15:00:22.340 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init No provider classes found.
07-Oct-2016 15:00:22.663 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.register Registering com.coolbooks.listener.JacksonOMP as a provider class
07-Oct-2016 15:00:22.663 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.register Registering com.coolbooks.rest.basentity.BaseEntity as a root resource class
07-Oct-2016 15:00:22.663 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.register Registering com.coolbooks.rest.cart.Cart as a root resource class
07-Oct-2016 15:00:22.663 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.register Registering com.coolbooks.rest.category.Category as a root resource class
07-Oct-2016 15:00:22.663 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.register Registering com.coolbooks.rest.content.Content as a root resource class
07-Oct-2016 15:00:22.663 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.register Registering com.coolbooks.rest.crawled.Product as a root resource class
07-Oct-2016 15:00:22.663 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.register Registering com.coolbooks.rest.geo.Location as a root resource class
07-Oct-2016 15:00:22.663 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.register Registering com.coolbooks.rest.price.Pricing as a root resource class
07-Oct-2016 15:00:22.663 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.register Registering com.coolbooks.rest.store.Store as a root resource class
07-Oct-2016 15:00:22.663 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM'
07-Oct-2016 15:00:22.742 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider Binding com.coolbooks.listener.JacksonOMP to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
07-Oct-2016 15:00:23.289 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider Binding com.coolbooks.rest.basentity.BaseEntity to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
07-Oct-2016 15:00:23.289 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider Binding com.coolbooks.rest.cart.Cart to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
07-Oct-2016 15:00:23.304 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider Binding com.coolbooks.rest.category.Category to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
07-Oct-2016 15:00:23.304 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider Binding com.coolbooks.rest.content.Content to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
07-Oct-2016 15:00:23.304 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider Binding com.coolbooks.rest.crawled.Product to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
07-Oct-2016 15:00:23.304 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider Binding com.coolbooks.rest.geo.Location to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
07-Oct-2016 15:00:23.304 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider Binding com.coolbooks.rest.price.Pricing to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
07-Oct-2016 15:00:23.320 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider Binding com.coolbooks.rest.store.Store to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
07-Oct-2016 15:00:23.351 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\webapps\coolbooks-rest.war has finished in 6,851 ms
07-Oct-2016 15:00:23.351 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\webapps\docs
07-Oct-2016 15:00:23.367 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\webapps\docs has finished in 16 ms
07-Oct-2016 15:00:23.367 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\webapps\examples
07-Oct-2016 15:00:23.506 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\webapps\examples has finished in 139 ms
07-Oct-2016 15:00:23.508 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\webapps\host-manager
07-Oct-2016 15:00:23.525 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\webapps\host-manager has finished in 17 ms
07-Oct-2016 15:00:23.526 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\webapps\manager
07-Oct-2016 15:00:23.541 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\webapps\manager has finished in 15 ms
07-Oct-2016 15:00:23.542 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\webapps\ROOT
07-Oct-2016 15:00:28.382 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
07-Oct-2016 15:00:28.518 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.coolbooks.rest
07-Oct-2016 15:00:28.546 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.logClasses Root resource classes found:
  class com.coolbooks.rest.category.Category
  class com.coolbooks.rest.crawled.Product
  class com.coolbooks.rest.cart.Cart
  class com.coolbooks.rest.basentity.BaseEntity
  class com.coolbooks.rest.geo.Location
  class com.coolbooks.rest.content.Content
  class com.coolbooks.rest.price.Pricing
  class com.coolbooks.rest.store.Store
07-Oct-2016 15:00:28.546 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init No provider classes found.
07-Oct-2016 15:00:28.887 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.register Registering com.coolbooks.listener.JacksonOMP as a provider class
07-Oct-2016 15:00:28.887 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.register Registering com.coolbooks.rest.basentity.BaseEntity as a root resource class
07-Oct-2016 15:00:28.889 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.register Registering com.coolbooks.rest.cart.Cart as a root resource class
07-Oct-2016 15:00:28.889 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.register Registering com.coolbooks.rest.category.Category as a root resource class
07-Oct-2016 15:00:28.890 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.register Registering com.coolbooks.rest.content.Content as a root resource class
07-Oct-2016 15:00:28.890 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.register Registering com.coolbooks.rest.crawled.Product as a root resource class
07-Oct-2016 15:00:28.891 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.register Registering com.coolbooks.rest.geo.Location as a root resource class
07-Oct-2016 15:00:28.891 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.register Registering com.coolbooks.rest.price.Pricing as a root resource class
07-Oct-2016 15:00:28.891 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.register Registering com.coolbooks.rest.store.Store as a root resource class
07-Oct-2016 15:00:28.895 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM'
07-Oct-2016 15:00:28.961 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider Binding com.coolbooks.listener.JacksonOMP to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
07-Oct-2016 15:00:29.336 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider Binding com.coolbooks.rest.basentity.BaseEntity to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
07-Oct-2016 15:00:29.336 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider Binding com.coolbooks.rest.cart.Cart to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
07-Oct-2016 15:00:29.351 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider Binding com.coolbooks.rest.category.Category to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
07-Oct-2016 15:00:29.351 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider Binding com.coolbooks.rest.content.Content to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
07-Oct-2016 15:00:29.351 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider Binding com.coolbooks.rest.crawled.Product to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
07-Oct-2016 15:00:29.351 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider Binding com.coolbooks.rest.geo.Location to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
07-Oct-2016 15:00:29.351 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider Binding com.coolbooks.rest.price.Pricing to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
07-Oct-2016 15:00:29.351 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory.getComponentProvider Binding com.coolbooks.rest.store.Store to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
07-Oct-2016 15:00:29.383 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\apps\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\webapps\ROOT has finished in 5,841 ms
07-Oct-2016 15:00:29.383 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
07-Oct-2016 15:00:29.398 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
07-Oct-2016 15:00:29.398 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 12929 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually type in the application context in the deployments tab.